# Как поменять шрифт в css?

Tags: html, css

Что то туплю сильно. Использую свойство css font-family. Какие то шрифты не пытался подключить, он не хочет менять шрифт. Что я не улавливаю?

```css
@fontface {
    font-family: bn;
    src: url("fonts/BebasNeue.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/BebasNeue.woff2") format("woff2");
}

@fontface {
    font-family: "lobster";
    src: url("fonts/lobster.woff") format("woff");
}

@fontface {
    font-family: "os";
    src: url("fonts/OpenSans.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/OpenSans.woff2") format("woff2");
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: math;
}

#header .write {
     margin-left: 10%;
     margin-top: 1.5%;
     width: 15%;
     float: left;
}

.count {
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.count p {
    float: right;
    color: #a1a1a1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Верстка моего первого шаблона</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf=8">
            <meta meta="description" content="Первый раз версткаю шаблон">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
             <div id="header">
                   <div class="write">
                       <img src="css/images/write.jpg" alt="#"/>
                   </div>
                   
                   <div class="count">
                        <p>Вот результат</p>
                        <img src="css/images/basket.jpg" alt="basket"/>
                   </div>
             </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

[image: Внешний вид текста]

Сначала я пытался менять шрифты через селектор класса к P, потом пытался применить ко всему body а ничего не меняется. Только начал изучать вертску, ничего не понимаю. Пытался подключить и те шрифты что скачал и подключил через fontface а потом и стандартные а внешний вид текста не меняется.

Comment: Что-то непонятно... Подключаете одни шрифты, а назначаете другой.

Comment: Это как пример я привел,потому что подключенные шрифты вообще не работают,попробовал подключить math. Ну вообще я сейчас попробовал Arial и они подействовали. Похоже что у меня просто нету в браузере шрифта math,а те что я подключил, подключены неправильно или скачаны неправильно. Короче,буду разбираться,похоже нашел зацепку

Comment: Все, разобрался, свойство font-face через дефис пишется,поэтому шрифты не подсоединялись, а шрифта math нету на моем компьютере видимо